# Transcoding is not working for mp4(H.264, AAC) and 3gp but for avi and webm

Tags: node.js, gridfs

Goal : Mobiles send different video formats, I would like to transcode them to mp4 so that it will be played everywhere then store them in GridFS and send `fileid` as response, whenever a user want to download video he/she will pass `fileid` as input

Current code receives data as stream and write it to gridFS, but transcoding is not working. please suggest me an approach. This is do or die situation for me.

I have below code to receive stream, transcode and write it to GFS

```
        var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
            filename: (fileid.toString()) + ".mp4",
            _id : fileid,
            mode : "w",
            content_type  : "video/mp4"
        });

        new Transcoder(stream)
            .videoCodec('h264')
            .videoBitrate(800 * 1000)
            .fps(25)
            .aspectRatio(1.7777777)
            .audioCodec('libfaac')
            .sampleRate(44100)
            .channels(2)
            .audioBitrate(128 * 1000)
            .format('mp4')
        .on('finish', function () {
            req.custom = fileid;
            next();
        }).stream().pipe(writestream);
```

Errors :
I receive error `Error: FFmpeg error: Error opening filters!` when I upload `.mp4` with `H.264, AAC` codec but works fine if I upload `.avi` files

Does not work on `3gp` too

Comment: I'm quick to say this is not an issue with node.js, but an issue with ffmpeg. What NPM module are you using for `Transcoder`?

Comment: @zamnuts Yes I am using `stream-transcoder`

Comment: can you transcode a .mp4 with H.264/AAC or a 3gp file with _just_ `ffmpeg` via CLI (i.e. without node)?

Comment: @zamnuts Will try and let you know in few mins

Comment: @zamnuts Yes its working with this code `ffmpeg -i H264_test4_Talkingheadclipped_mp4_480x320.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: it has been a while since i've tinkered with ffmpeg, but you're specifying `'h264'` in `videoCodec` but passing `libx264` to `-vcodec` (alias of `-c:v`), also [see `stream-transcoder` src for `videoCodec`](https://github.com/trenskow/stream-transcoder.js/blob/master/lib/transcoder.js#L305-L308)... i do understand that libx264 = h264, but perhaps ffmpeg does not. get a list of available codecs via `ffmpeg -codecs` and see if h264 is in there. you're also using `libfaac` for `-c:a` but using a copy stream in your CLI version. retest the CLI ffmpeg with an exact copy of your nodejs implementation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52736/discussion-between-zamnuts-and-redv)